# How do I give a covariance matrix to scipy.odr?

Tags: python, scipy, regression

I am trying to do a correlated fit of both x and y data, however when I pass in covariance matrices for my x and y measurements, I get the following error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-173-273ef42c6f27> in <module>()
----> 1 odrout = theodr.run()

/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/odr/odrpack.pyc in run(self)
   1098         for attr in kwd_l:
   1099             obj = getattr(self, attr)
-> 1100             if obj is not None:
   1101                 kwds[attr] = obj
   1102 

ValueError: could not convert we to a suitable array
```

Here is a minimal NOT working example that triggers this error on my machine:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.odr as spodr

# make x and y data for a function
xx = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
yy = 2.*np.sin(3*xx) - 1
# randomize both variables a bit, and make 10 measurements
# of each data point
xdat = xx + np.random.normal(scale=0.3, size=(10,100))
ydat = yy + np.random.normal(scale=0.3, size=(10, 100))
# the function I will fit to
sin = lambda beta, x: beta[0]*np.sin(beta[1] * x) + beta[2]
# the covariance matrices for both data sets, here I summed over
# the 10 measurements I made for both my x and y data
xcov = np.cov(xdat.transpose())
ycov = np.cov(ydat.transpose())
# setup the odr data
odrdat = spodr.RealData(np.mean(xdat, axis=0),
                        np.mean(ydat, axis=0), covx=xcov, covy=ycov)
# set up the odr model
model = spodr.Model(sin)
# make the odr object
theodr = spodr.ODR(odrdat, model, beta0=[2,3,-1])
# run the odr object
odrout = theodr.run()
```

I can't seem to see why the matrices I'm passing are not suitable arrays.  From the docs:

> Covariance of x covx is an array of covariance matrices of x and are converted to weights by performing a matrix inversion on each observation’s covariance matrix.

This makes me think I should be passing a covariance matrix for each data point, but I don't have that type of information, and I don't think I need it.  For a correlated fit it should be enough to have the covariances between all the data.  For instance, in `scipy.curve_fit` you can pass in a 2d-array as a covariance matrix for the y-data, you don't need one for every single point.

Is there a particular way I should be passing these covariance matrices?